# Linkedin reporting API return empty LinkedIn Ad Analytics Retrieval Issue: Empty Results despite Visible Campaigns

Tags: linkedin-api

Need help with LinkedIn Ad campaign analytics retrieval. Results are empty, even though campaigns are visible in Ad manager.

GET request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=4&dateRange.start.month=9&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.end.day=14&dateRange.end.month=9&dateRange.end.year=2023&timeGranularity=ALL&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:ID
```

results

```
{
    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": []
    },
    "elements": []
}
```

Any assistance appreciated. Thanks!